# cast a String to sql time

Tags: java, sql, mysql

How we cast a string into time type with mysql in java
So String------->java.sql.time

thanks.

Comment: Modern comment: Since JDBC 4.2 you should no longer use `java.sql.Time` but `java.time.LocalTime`. See [the answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74553729/5772882).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends entirely on the format of your `String`, so I would use a `SimpleDateFormat` to parse the string into a `java.util.Date`; then you can extract the millisecond time value from that Date and pass it into a `java.sql.Time()`. Like this:

```
String s = /* your date string here */;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(/* your date format string here */);
long ms = sdf.parse(s).getTime();
Time t = new Time(ms);
```

Comment: 2024... Still works! got me from string "09:30" to java.sql.Time() and the ms ended up being 52200000

Answer (score 10):

```
java.sql.Time.valueOf("String");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
java.sql.Time.parse("String");
```

But that's deprecated, and replaced by [DateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) Parse.

Answer (score 1):

## Update: `java.time.LocalTime`

The Question and other Answers use terribly flawed date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

To represent a time-only value, without a date, and without a time zone or offset-from-UTC, use [`java.time.LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) class.

To parse text in standard ISO 8601 format:

```
LocalTime t = LocalTime.parse( "15:30" ) ;
```

Write to database with [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) 4.2 and later:

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , t ) ;
```

Read from database:

```
LocalTime t = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalTime.class ) ;
```

Search Stack Overflow to learn more. Date-time matters have been addressed extensively. And see [tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).