# Gson time deserilization

Tags: java, android, json, gson, deserialization

I have a JSON string that I want to deserilizie using Gson - `{"Id":3,"Title":"Roskilde","Description":"Famous Danske festival","StartingTime":"2016-06-12T00:00:00","Duration":"02:02:00"}` 
The error I get when I try to deserilize the Duration field:

> Unparseable date: "02:02:00"

The deserilizer(my idea was to add two possible formats of date deserialization):

```
Gson gSon=  new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateDeserializer()).create();


private static final String[] DATE_FORMATS = new String[] {
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",
        "HH:mm:ss"
};


private class DateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type typeOF,
                            JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        for (String format : DATE_FORMATS) {
            try {
                return new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US).parse(jsonElement.getAsString());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
            }
        }
        throw new JsonParseException("Unparseable date: \"" + jsonElement.getAsString()
                + "\". Supported formats: " + Arrays.toString(DATE_FORMATS));
    }
}
```

and my Event Class(as you can see "Duration" is not of a type date - it's of the type Time - what should I do to make the deserilizer read Duration as type time not date?

```
    private int Id;
private String Title;
private String Description;
private Date StartingTime;
private Time Duration;
public Event(int id, String title,String description, String place, Date startingTime, Time duration)
{
    this.Id = id;
    this.Description = description;
    this.Title = title;
    this.StartingTime = startingTime;
    this.Duration = duration;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add another class for Time deserialization - make sure you convert the return value to "Time".
(Also see: [cast a String to sql time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731443/cast-a-string-to-sql-time))

```
    private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
    private static final String TIME_FORMAT = "HH:mm:ss";

    private class DateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {

        @Override
        public Date deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type typeOF,
                                JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
                try {
                    return new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT, Locale.US).parse(jsonElement.getAsString());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                }

            throw new JsonParseException("Unparseable date: \"" + jsonElement.getAsString()
                    + "\". Supported formats: " + DATE_FORMAT);
        }
    }

    private class TimeDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Time> {

        @Override
        public Time deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type typeOF,
                                JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
                try {

                    String s = jsonElement.getAsString();
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(TIME_FORMAT, Locale.US);
                    sdf.parse(s);
                    long ms = sdf.parse(s).getTime();
                    Time t = new Time(ms);
                    return t;
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                }
            throw new JsonParseException("Unparseable time: \"" + jsonElement.getAsString()
                    + "\". Supported formats: " + TIME_FORMAT);
        }
    }
```

Register both classes:

```
    GsonBuilder gSonBuilder=  new GsonBuilder();
    gSonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateDeserializer());
    gSonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Time.class, new TimeDeserializer());
    Gson gSon = gSonBuilder.create();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should register a deserializer for both Date and Time. Something like this:

```
try{
    // Convert JSON-string to a List of Event objects
    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Event>>(){}.getType();
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonDeserializer<Date>() {
        @Override
        public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
            try{
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
                return df.parse(json.getAsString());
            }
            catch(ParseException ex){
                return null;
            }
    });
    gsonBuilder.RegisterTypeAdapter(Time.class, new JsonDeserializer<Time>(){
        @Override
        public Time deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
                try{
                    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
                    return df.parse(json.getAsString());
                }
                catch(ParseException ex){}
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
    Gson eventGson = gsonBuilder.create();
    events = dateGson.fromJson(json, listType);
}
catch(JsonParseException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

PS: This code is untested, since I didn't had a lot of time. But I think you get the general idea. You just need two JsonDeserializers, one for time and one for Date.