# how to convert a string into java.sql.time

Tags: java

How can I convert a String value to java.sql.time?

I have a scenario in which user gives the input time value as string.

For example: 10 PM

I have to store this value in Database as time stamp. Could any one please help me solving this problem. Mainly I want to write the getter and setter for this scenario.

Comment: How about a "google search" ?

Comment: See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74553729/642706) on a similar Question, using the modern `java.time.LocalTime` class.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    String t = "10:34:34";
    Time time = Time.valueOf(t);
    System.out.println(time);
```

its working.

Comment: Update: The `java.sql.Time` class has been supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Replaced specifically by `java.time.LocalTime`.